Collision probability of hash function $(ax + b)\bmod m$
I'm trying to calculate the probability of collision for the following family of hash functions:
$$h_{a, b}(x) = (ax+ b) \mathrm{mod}{m} \quad \quad m\in\mathrm{Z}_p, \ a\in\{0, 1, \ldots, m - 1\}, \ b\in \{1, 2, \ldots, m-1\}$$
Note that the domain of $h$ is $\{0, 1, ..., m^k - 1\}$ for $k \ge 2$.

From the search I've done this might require number theory which I have never touched. Best I can do is write this for two numbers $x, y$ that collide:
$$\begin{aligned} & h_{a,b}(x) = h_{a,b}(y) \\ \\\implies &(ax+b) = (ay + b) + km \quad \quad k\in \mathrm{Z}^* \\ \\ \implies & ax = ay + km \\ \\ \implies& x = y+ \frac{km}{a} \quad (1) \end{aligned}\\$$
So, I'm basically trying to find for a number $x$ how many numbers $y$ give the same hash. Dividing this by $m^k$ which is the number of all possible inputs to $h$, should give me the probability I'm looking for.
I suppose $(1)$ holds for all cases where $\frac{km}{a}$ is an integer. And I think that's where number theory comes to play (if not earlier). I'm looking for those values of $k$ that make $\frac{km}{a}$ an integer. How can I proceed? It's clear that multiples of $a$ will do, but there might be more than this.

When you say the domain of $h$ is ${0, 1, ..., m^k - 1}$ you fix $a$ and $b$. Then the answer is correct, however, in your question you consider $a$ and $b$ not fixed which contradicts the assumption. Also, by choosing different $a$ and $b$ one select another function that contradicts the definition of hash function that they are determinsitic...

@kelalaka You are right. I meant to write "family" of hash functions. I've now corrected it.

You have some mistakes; multiplying by $a^{-1}$ is possible if $a$ is invertible. $\frac{km}{a}$ is not division, it is $kma^{-1}$

@kelalaka How is $\frac{km}{a}$ different from $kma^{-1}$ ? Why can't I divide by $a$ if it's not "invertible"?

$h_{a, b}(x) = (ax+ b)\ \mathrm{mod}{\ m}$ looks pretty much like an LCG used for pseudo random number generators. If $a,\ b,\ m$ comply the Hull–Dobell theorem it's a full period LCG, thus for $x\lt m$ results are unique.

Wow, I'd never heard of LCGs. Do they apply here however? How is the period of this LCG related to the problem? In LCGs, you enter the result right back into the function to produce the next element of the sequence. We are not doing something like this when looking for hash collisions. If you can elaborate a bit it'd be great.
Also, $x \in {0, 1, \ldots, m^k -1}$ . So  $x<m$ is not true in this scenario.

@JohnKatsantas -- I'm not convinced, when I look at the CRC-32/MPEG-2 and CRC-32/ISO-HDLC algorithms, a file to check is XORed byte-wise to input $x$.
